# Data flow issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I have a function inside a directive that makes a query (and gets results, according to the console). The problem is that I can't seem to be able to store those results into a factory, and pass them to a controller.

This is the directive:

```
scope.getVersions = function(release) {
      if (angular.isUndefined(release)) return;

      musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions(release.id)
        .success(function(data) {
          dataService = data.versions;
          console.log(dataService);
        });

};
```

The console shows that dataService contains an array with the results.
Then, I try to store it into a factory:

```
app.factory('dataService', [function(){
  return { items: [] };
}]);
```

And I call it in a controller:

```
function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.versions = dataService.items;
  console.log($scope.versions);
}
```

But both items and $scope.versions come back an empty array. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a backing field to store that data, and use setter and geter functions for writing and reading respectively:

```
app.factory('dataService', [function(){
   var _items={};
   return { 
          setItems:function(value){
             _items=value;
          },
          getItems:function(){
             return _items;
          }
  };
}]);
```

And for setting the data:

```
 musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions(release.id)
        .success(function(data) {
          dataService.setItems(data.versions);
          console.log(dataService);
        });
```

and reading:

```
function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.versions = dataService.getItems();
  console.log($scope.versions);
}
```

[See demo plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5MEcnCcH84hIrH5jR7z?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I've tried your code but comes back ReferenceError: dataService is not defined.

Comment: 1 sec, let me make  a plunk

Comment: Wait, I'll give u mine, almost finished

Comment: There you go. If you search for an artist and click on a release, you'll see the error on the console. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBdvtN6ayo59017rLKPs?p=preview)

Comment: @EricMitjans that's because you're not injecting `dataService` into the directives constructor, do this: `app.directive('release', ['musicInfoService','dataService',  function(musicInfoService,dataService) {`

Comment: Still undefined. Damnit : )

Comment: I can't see the undefined error anymore in that plunk, can you paste the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: You're right, the error is not there anymore, but the  $scope.versions is still coming back empty. I've changed the code some many times I don't know what I'm doing anymore..

Comment: Eric, I think you're doing a lot of things fundamentally wrong. Your $scope.versions is naturally undefined since you're never really instantiating the `VersionController` which is responsible for filling up $scope.versions with data.

Comment: Mohammad, you're right, I'm encountering exactly this problem, first item clicked comes empty because is initially undefined, and then the results shown under each element doesn't correspond to this same element. I'll create a new question for it and see how to plan for the first undefined element and the possible .error cases. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a misunderstanding of angular factories going on here. You're trying to set dataService = , which will never work.

As Mohammad mentioned, you need to have a variable set outside of your return value in the factory and the return value is basically an object with functions that allow you to manipulate your constant. So what you need is a getter "getItems()" for getting the items, and a setter "addItem(item)" for adding an item to your items array.

So you're never directly injecting your "items" into a controller, you're injecting a bunch of functions that can get or manipulate your "items".

```
scope.getVersions = function(release) {
      if (angular.isUndefined(release)) return;

      musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions(release.id)
        .success(function(data) {
          dataService.addItem(data.versions);
          console.log(dataService.getItems());
        });
};

app.factory('dataService', [function(){
  var items = [];
  return {
    addItem: function(item) {
      items.push(item);
    },
    getItems: function() {
      return items;
    }
  };
}]);

function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.$watch(dataService.getItems, function(items) {
    $scope.versions = items;
    console.log($scope.versions);
  });
}
```